# Can I use "return" as figurative of "become"

Tags: meaning, verbs

Example:

> Some day we will return strangers.

Meaning to say, "Some day we will forget each other and we will go back to the moment when we didn't know each other".

I hope I'm clear. It's meant to be used in a song so keep in mind it's not formal writing. At the same time, I do want to be sure I don't mislead the listener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need either "to being" or "as."

"Some day, we will return to being strangers."
This is a pretty straightforward statement of fact.

"Some day, we will return as strangers."
This is a little more loaded.  It implies that you're both headed your own way, but that you'll return to where you are now in the future.  When you do, you expect you'll again be strangers to each other, even though you're back in the same place.  This sounds like what you're going for.

Comment: wow thank you, the full explanation is amazingly so on point....I'm italian and i love to learn this subtle variations thanks!